# Simple example of functional equation in Banach Algebra and how to solve it

Tags: functional-equations, banach-algebras

In my readings through Banach Algebra I noticed something. For real functions for example we know that the functional equation

$$
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)
$$

Has as solution $f(x) = e^x$.
Now since bounded operators in $L^p(\mu)$ form a Banach Algebra as well I observed that a similar relationship holds for the translation operator. If $(T_yf)(x) = f(x -y)$ we have the relationship

$$
T_{x+y} = T_x T_y
$$

Which resembles pretty much the first functional equation I saw. From a random reading yesterday about quantum mechanics I saw that the translation operator can be expressed as something like an exponential as well. I wonder if therefore there's some techniques for solving functional equations in Banach Algebra that would allow to represent operators using functional equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the called "One-parameter Semigroup" in mathematics. For example, Peter Lax's Functional analysis text, Chapter 34 showed that if $T_0=Id$ and $\forall x,y\ge0, T_xT_y = T_{x+y}$ and $T$ is continuous at $0$ (that is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} T_x = Id$), then $T$ must be of the form $T_t = e^{tG}$ where $G$ is known as the infinitesimal generator of the one-parameter semi-group. The proof is essentially to write $G$ as log of $T_t$, and it's not hard to show the power series for the usual log converges around $1$, because $T_t$ will be close to $Id$, hence its norm is not far from $1$.

Answer (score 0):

About the exponential operator, it is well known in quantum mechanics, but I have us it in the past for a numerical method to solve the propagation of laser beams, named "Split-Step Fourier Method".

I left the wikipedia links hoping they will help you to understand how this operator can be used and its equations solved (since its a numerical method, I believe could be an example for a Banach Space):
[Shift Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), [Split-Step Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-step_method), [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff)

Comment: I think what I'd like to know is whether the exponential operator can be defined as solution of the functional equation I gave (the one involving the translation operator).

Comment: On the last links, on the special cases [[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases)], it is explained that for two operators to be equal to $e^X \cdot e^Y = e^{X+Y}$ is required that $X$ and $Y$ commute: $[X,Y]=0$, so, since the functional equation is defined for the translation operator, who can be represented as an exponential operator as is shown in [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Definition)], to happen the right side the exponential operator "exponents" have to commute in a Banach Lie Group, as example.

Comment: I think the problem is that in [1] the assumption made is that you can perform a taylor expansion of the function. Which is not the assumption I am making since I am assuming $L^p$. Moreover I was wondering if specifically there's a technique to "solve" somewhat $T_{x+y} = T_x T_y$ to end up with $e^{-y \frac{d}{dx}}$.

Comment: I am afraid we are seeing the problem from a different angle: lets start from the right side, $T_x T_y = \log(e^{T_x}e^{T_y})=T_x + T_y + \frac{1}{2}[T_x,T_y]+\frac{1}{12}([T_x,[T_x,T_y]]+[T_y,[T_y,T_x]])+\cdots$ the monstrosity derived by the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Formula. By the other side, for the left part, I will make the following assumption $T_x(T_y) = T_{x+y} = T_x + T_y$, i.e., $T_u$ is a linear map [[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map)], so the only way to both side to be equal is that $[T_x,T_y]=0$, so in general, some constraints must be true to be equal.

Comment: I think there's a miss-understanding. You're going from $T_x$ to $e^{T_x}$, I want to show that $T_x = e^G$ where $G$ is another linear operator. For example in the space of differentiable functions $T_x = e^{-x\frac{d}{dx}}$, how does this generalize to $L^p$ for example? My only thought was that since $B(L^p(X))$ is a Banach algebra and since $$ T_x T_y = T_{x+y}$$ I saw the resemblance with $f(x)f(y) = f(x + y)$ which has a solution an exponential.

Comment: I think essentially we're talking about different problems, because in your case you have $T_x$ and $e^{T_x}$ which are not the same operator, instead I am looking to represent $T_x = e^G$ where $G$ is another operator.

Comment: Maybe you are right and I don't understand your question (English is not native for me), what I was trying to pinpoint is that for some operator to behave as $T_x T_y = T_{x+y}$ must happen a lot of circumstances that aren't true in general, even for the Shift Operator where if $[X.Y]\neq 0$ the exponential split $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ don´t happen.... when I was using the split-step Fourier method to simulate laser beams propagation through 1D thin holograms, I have to add another term of the expansion because it wasn't true for the differential equation that linear and non-linear stages commuted.

Comment: Looking for something totally unrelated I found these on Wikipedia, maybe it could be helpful to your research. Hope it helps you. [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) and [Functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).